# Getting a weird percent sign in printf output in terminal with C

Tags: c, printf, zsh

I have this `printf` statement at the end of my program:

```
printf("%d", total_candies);
```

`total_candies` is an `int`, and while I expect everything to work correctly, along with the actual number, I'm getting a weird percent sign at the end.
[image]

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Is that your console prompt, perhaps? Try adding a newline to your output: `printf("%d\n", total_candies);`

Comment: Please update your question to show a complete program that exhibits the problem. How do you know that the weird percent character is being printed by that specific statement? Could it be your shell prompt?

Comment: @KeithThompson That's the only printf/or any console logging statement I have.

Comment: I think some zsh configs default to displaying output without a final newline that way. Quick test: does "echo -n hi" have the same behavior?

Comment: That character is part of your zsh prompt.

Comment: @cobbal: I think you've nailed it. When I type `echo -n hello` at a `zsh` prompt, I get the same reverse-video `%` character. You should post that as an answer. (The fix is to add a `\n` to the format string -- which you should do anyway, regardless of which shell you're using.)

Comment: @iharob: No, zsh prints that reverse-video `%` character when a program's output doesn't end in a newline.

Comment: @Keith Thompson Still it is something related to zsh not a c programming problem.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

When (non-null) output from a program doesn't include a trailing newline, zsh adds that color-inverted `%` to indicate that and moves to the next line before printing the prompt; it's generally more convenient than bash's behavior, just starting the command prompt where the output ended.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about this behaviour of zsh. Now that I think about it, it is indeed more useful than bash's behaviour.

Comment: Noticed the same behaviour with golang fmt.Prinf("%d", a) this solution also applicable there

Answer (score 5):

Running `PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''` into the command line fixes this.

Answer (score 2):

In `zsh`

`PROMPT_SP`
Attempt to preserve a partial line **(i.e. a line that did not end with a newline)** that would otherwise be covered up by the command prompt due to the `PROMPT_CR` option. This works by outputting some cursor-control characters, including a series of spaces, that should make the terminal wrap to the next line when a partial line is present (note that this is only successful if your terminal has automatic margins, which is typical).

When a partial line is preserved, by default you will see an `inverse+bold character at the end of the partial line`: a `‘%’` for a `normal user` or a `‘#’ for` root`. If set, the shell parameter` PROMPT_EOL_MARK` can be used to customize how the end of partial lines are shown.