# C++ result on visual studio code (mac)

Tags: c++

[Code question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZXWD.png)

Hello to everybody,

I have a question, I am new on mac and also programming in C++. I am starting to program with visual studio code and after my third program I saw that in the result I can see the percentage result after the correct result is shown.

Do you know why this may happen?

Regards,
Eneko

Comment: Code should be in your question directly as text, not as an image.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cause, but your program isn't printing newline character at end of output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a weird percent sign in printf output in terminal with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238564/getting-a-weird-percent-sign-in-printf-output-in-terminal-with-c)