# Why does a % percentage appear at the end of the output to standard out but not when I use endl?

Tags: c++, stream, cout

Why is there a trailing % at the end of this output?  I've tried flushing the stream (not endl), however when I end the stream with a call to endl it gets rid of the %.  Any help here would be much appreciated.

```
template<class T>
void print_collection(T * t){
        for(int i = 0; i < t->size()-1; ++i){
                cout << t->at(i) << ", ";
        }
        std::cout<< t->at(t->size() -1);
        std::cout<<flush;
}

int main(){
        int n_A = 5;
        int A[] = {2, 3, -2, 34, -29};

        vector<int> vec(A, A + n_A);
        sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

        print_collection(&vec);
        return 0;
}

OUTPUT
-29, -2, 2, 3, 34%
```

Here is more information about the compiler, I'm using macOS 10.15.4:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 array.cpp -o array

g++ Information:
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: This should answer the question for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238564/getting-a-weird-percent-sign-in-printf-output-in-terminal-with-c

Comment: Thanks WBuck!  It was my shell, not my program.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate question.  Thanks @WBuck!

@Kevin states:
When (non-null) output from a program doesn't include a trailing newline, zsh adds that color-inverted % to indicate that and moves to the next line before printing the prompt; it's generally more convenient than bash's behavior, just starting the command prompt where the output ended.

[Getting a weird percent sign in printf output in terminal with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238564/getting-a-weird-percent-sign-in-printf-output-in-terminal-with-c)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a similar question ages back.

This could potentially be from your export shell, not the output to the program itself.
So before you change anything major, take a look into that.

Depending on what you're doing-- a good way to prevent that from showing up would be by adding a newline to the output within your print function.

[image: Newline to print function example]