# GCC compile issue

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, zsh

im new to C

compiled .c file on mac gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    unsigned char a =  1 ; // 0000 0001 8 bit 
    unsigned char b = 2 ; // 0000 0010 

    unsigned char c;

    a = a  >> 1 ;

    printf ("a = %d  \n ", a  );

    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxYtt.png)

getting
% things what is wrong with this ?

Comment: The '%' character is most likely part of your terminal prompt. Nothing is wrong with the program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a weird percent sign in printf output in terminal with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238564/getting-a-weird-percent-sign-in-printf-output-in-terminal-with-c)

Comment: @Azad: Look at the screenshot, the part before calling the program: PS1 is obviously set up differently. While the `%` indeed looks like a default zsh prompt, this could occur only if `bitwise` would open a new zsh child process. There is nothing in the original C program which would do this.

Comment: @QDT: Remove the space after the `\n` in your code