# VS code showing % symbol at end everytime in the output How to solve it?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, output, printf

VS code showing  % symbol at end every time in the output, How to solve it?
[image]

Comment: Looks like your shell's prompt.  Did you not notice how there's always a `%` next to where your shell asks for input?  Try `printf("hello\n");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a weird percent sign in printf output in terminal with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238564/getting-a-weird-percent-sign-in-printf-output-in-terminal-with-c)