# PyCharm is adding color inverted % and new line after reset

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, zsh, curses

### The problem

I'm getting this color inverted % sign followed by a new line after resetting pycharm's terminal. This does NOT happens on ubuntu terminal.

In a newly generate terminal session everything works as expected. The command line prompts me for a command.

[image]

I enter a command to run a python script and it works fine.

[image]

But then, if I use the reset command, the following happens.

[image]

And if I try to execute my script again, this will happen.

[image]

I'm using this main.py script in every call to it.

`main.py`

```py
def main():
    print("Hello World")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Even though there is no code of it in the main.py anymore, I believe it is worth noting that I was having some fun with [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) before this happened.

### What I've learned

It seems that this inverted percentage sign happens in [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) (which is the shell I'm using) when:

> a non-null output from a program doesn't include a trailing new line (...)

as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27238697/5090416). But this doesn't explain the new line after it, why it keeps happening and a way to solve it.

How to stop this behavior from happening?

Comment: What happens if you use `clear` instead of `reset`?

Comment: None of this is Python-related. Please [edit] to show your `zsh` prompt configuration.

Comment: Same behavior happens when using `clear` instead of `reset`.

Comment: You mean my .zshrc?