# Why does my Java output string end with the % character at the end?

Tags: java, string, loops

The version of Java I'm using with Linux is:

- openjdk version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 16.0.2+7)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.2+7, mixed mode)

*This is the code I used to compile from the Head-First Java book:*

```
public class DooBee {
public static void main(String[] args) {    
  int x = 1;
  while (x < 3) {
    System.out.print("Doo");
    System.out.print("Bee");
    x = x + 1;
  }
    if( x == 3) {
        System.out.print("Do");
    }
}
```

}

*I compiled it as such:*

> javac DooBee.java

> java DooBee

*This is the output:*

```
DooBeeDooBeeDo%
```

Why is that special character(%) present at the end of the string and how do I write my code to get rid of it?

Comment: Can't reproduce, your code does not produce this. Since you don't print a newline anywhere in your code, it's possible that the `%` is simply the prompt of your shell. Try adding an empty `System.out.println()` add the end of your code.

Comment: I've added a System.out.println() right after System.out.print("Do") and the special character doesn't appear anymore. Also I've written and compiled the code in the shell so you are correct.Why did it appear in the first place?

Comment: I bet it still appears, but just a line lower, where you expect your shell prompt, because that's what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you are using [ZSH](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/) terminal which automatically ends line (or rather "starting new line in the same line") with `%` character (and `#` for root user) if new line wasn't provided by the process, creating something named [partial line](https://jeffreytse.net/computer/2020/10/21/terminal-partial-line-prompt-feature.html)

Please notice that you are using `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`

---

Read more here:

- [Why ZSH ends a line with a highlighted percent symbol](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol)
- [Getting a weird percent sign in printf output in terminal with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238564/getting-a-weird-percent-sign-in-printf-output-in-terminal-with-c)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the % comes from your java program, but from your shell. The last output from your program is a `print()` rather than a `println()`. This will result in the output ending without a line break. The shell you are running will come back in the middle of an existing line. If it uses a % for a prompt, then that's why.
Change the last `print` to `println` and you are hopefully good. Try running it in an IDE or a different shell to make sure. Or perhaps change the prompt, just as a debugging measure?

Comment: I've changed the last `print()` to `println()` and now it appears correctly. I've  also written and compiled the program in the shell so it makes sense that the problem should be in the shell.