# % is appending to C- program output

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Issue: % is appending into my C program output. I also execute the program from Mac terminal. it also gives output followed by `"%"` sign. please suggest how to fix? Screenshot attached

**My Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num1,num2,sum;
    num1 = 20, num2 = 30;
    sum = num1 + num2;
    printf("the sum: %d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

**Program output from VS Code Terminal **

```
Jigneshs-MacBook-Air~  # gcc -o runme var.c
Jigneshs-MacBook-Air~  # ./runme           
the sum: 50%
```

**Expected Output**

```
the sum: 50
```

Platform details:
OS: MacOS BigSur (Apple M1 Chip)
IDE: VS Code (Version: 1.63.2)

Screenshot attached [image]

[image]

Comment: thanks @Yunnosch. adding new line "\n" to program output line. it has fixed. this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238564/getting-a-weird-percent-sign-in-printf-output-in-terminal-with-c) _italic_ **bold** helps. 
`printf("the sum: %d \n",sum);`

Answer (score 0):

Using a mac is not the problem, not adding a \n at the end of your output is causing this. [The % is autoinserted if there is no newline character](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#Prompting).

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238564/getting-a-weird-percent-sign-in-printf-output-in-terminal-with-c) another stackoverflow post with what I believe is the same problem.

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num1,num2,sum;
    num1 = 20, num2 = 30;
    sum = num1 + num2;
    printf("the sum: %d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not answer with fragments of already proposed duplicates. (Note that they were already propsed when you answered, earlier than my close vote....) Answering when obviously aware of other SO answers should be avoided and preferred to mark as duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

The '%' indicates where your output ends, when there is no newline character.
Add a newline ('\n') to the end of your output and the sign should be gone.

Comment: Please do not answer with unexplained fragments of already proposed duplicates. (Note that they were already propsed when you answered, earlier than my close vote....)